# Factoring a partially antisymmetric polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I am not an expert in algebra or algebraic geometry. However, I recently encountered the following problem :

Suppose we have a real polynomial $f$ of 4 variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ such that $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)= - f (x_3, x_4, x_1, x_2)$ i.e. the polynomial flips a sign when the *pair* $(x_1, x_2)$ is swapped with $(x_3, x_4)$. Can I say the following :

$$f=(x_1-x_3)g_1+ (x_2-x_4)g_2 + ((x_1-x_3)^2+ (x_2-x_4)^2) g_3$$  where $g_1, g_2, g_3$ are all real polynomials such that $g_i(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)= g_i (x_3, x_4, x_1, x_2)$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$ and $g_3(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)= - g_3 (x_3, x_4, x_1, x_2)$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Third term is a subset of the other two. Try relabeling in term of sum/difference variables.

Comment: Thanks, @Eric for your comment. I have edited the question and would highly appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 1):

*Partial answer.*

In the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(x_1-x_3,x_2-x_4)$ we have
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = -f(x_3,x_4,x_1,x_2) \equiv -f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),$$
hence $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \equiv 0$. Hence, $f$ is a linear combination of $x_1-x_3$ and $x_2 - x_4$.

Comment: This solution is great but I have a question. How do you make sure that the coefficients of $x_1-x_3$ and $x_2-x_4$ in the linear combination are symmetric polynomials w.r.t pairwise flip?

Comment: I don't know. I saw that requirement too late, that's why I added "Partial answer" as a disclaimer.